# Searching for files in Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008

I would always type *.* to search for files in Windows XP. With Windows 2008 Server, it gives folders along with files. How can I change the setting so that I only get files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll need to use [Advanced Query syntax](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/technicalresources/advquery.mspx).

```
name:~~someSearch NOT type:"File Folder"
```

Since your are trying to search for all files (excluding folders) you can search for this:

```
NOT type:"File Folder"
```

(The "NOT" must be in all caps)

The tables at the bottom of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page help.

Comment: Except for one folder called, "Downloaded Program Files", all returned results were files. I used:  \*.* NOT type:"File Folder"